Choosing number of groups in trajectory model
I am working with a group-based multi trajectory model, with two binary outcomes each measured at four time points. The results seem to be somewhat in conflict about what number of groups (four or six - five group is worse) is the best fit, and I wasn't sure how to adjudicate.
Specifically, the six group solution has better BIC (by ~100 points, so strong evidence), and generally higher odds of correct classification (OCC - 8.5-15 in the six group vs 5.7-12 in the four group), but the average posterior probability of assignment (APPA) falls below Nagin's recommended threshhold of >0.7 (.54 - .81 in six group, vs .69-.84 in four group).
How can I choose/justify the decision?
